# How to tune Typescript StencilJS with Jest to support ES6 dynamic module imports

Tags: typescript, d3.js, stenciljs, jest-puppeteer, ecmascript-2020

Many *Similair questions* here (...), but none that help me to get a *pure Stencil* configuration. The config-administration should be left to Stencil as much as possible IMO (...)

My Stencil component works fine, I tried virtually everything, but Jest spec-test that needs to import `d3-geo` keeps throwing me:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

/app/node_modules/d3-geo/src/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export {default as geoArea} from "./area.js";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
```

***What am I missing?***

I could probably use Babel to get this working, but that seems hacky. And I cannot imagine we actually need a Babel pre-wash to get ES6 module support.

App specifics:

- Node@14.16.0 (from docker-image buildkite/puppeteer)
- Stencil@2.6.0
- Jest@26.6.3
- Typescript@4.4.2
- Module that causes the error: [d3-geo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-geo)@3.0.1

I have jest config in package.json:

```
...
  "type": "module",
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node",
    "transform": {}
  },
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "es2015": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "es2020": "dist/index.js",
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "stencil test --spec --e2e",
    ...
...
```

And tsconfig contains:

```
...
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2020",
...
```

Comment: D3 just [converted to ES6 modules a month ago](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v7.0.0). Your options: point at an older version of  D3. Or read Sindre Sorhus’s [*Pure ESM package*](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c) (which D3's creator links to) and maybe also [Get Ready For ESM](https://blog.sindresorhus.com/get-ready-for-esm-aa53530b3f77)

Comment: Thanks @Iniogo for the heads up. I know that ES6 syntax is *fresh* in d3. That's interesting indeed.

But my question is really more about configuring Stencil with a Jest test suite that can use ES6 dynamic imports (or at least; I think that is my problem ...)

Comment: So far, I have lost an entire week to this issue - NOTHING I try works, and I cannot get past this - and I NEED to. If you found a solution, PLEASE post it here. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, we just decide to skip tests including d3-geo placements (how do we live with ourselves? :-/ )

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me was to add this in `stencil.config.ts`:

You use the `jest-preprocessor` as per the [docs](https://www.serkom.de/docs/testing/) specify, and you exclude the modules that are exported as ESM from the ignore pattern so it does it on them as well (initially tried `babel-jest` and `ts-jest` but I had other issues from using those solutions).

```js
// Can simply extend the list if we ever consume more esModules.
const esModules = [
  // dependencies of esm packages
].join('|');

export const config: Config = {
  //...
  transform: {
      '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|css)$': "@stencil/core/testing/jest-preprocessor"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank YOU! This was the fix needed and it's a bonus that there are no other dependencies or files involved!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `"esModuleInterop": true` to your tsconfig.json? ([link to TSConfig reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop))